# VBA needing to automatically fill a column with an if statement when column locations are not fixed

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to do the following:

Find a column called Employee SGrp, 
then add a column to the right of Employee SGrp which has the heading of Employee Classification as the first column. I then auto fill this column with a formula.

However the data is based on a report and the column location are not fixed (i.e. Employee SGrp may be in M one month and L the next). Therefore I can't use cell references like 'A2' in my formulas. In addition there are a few different options in the previous two columns so I am going to need to use an if statement as my formula to fill the columns. For example if "driver" write contractor, if part time write "permanent" if casual write "permanent".

I have added a column using the offset and resize features and have added add a value to serve as the heading. I have managed to put a formula in but only have it fill basic calculation such as sum or fill in a number) I have not been able to nest an if statement in this form and have also been unable to build the if statement properly. I can create a formula using fixed values (e.g. A2) but I need to be able to reference the column by name not fixed location since it isn't always in the same cell reference. I would appreciate any help in accomplishing this as I haven't found anything yet which will allow me to accomplish what I need to do.

```
'Insert a new column to the right of rngLocation
rngEmpClass.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Set rngNewCol = rngEmpClass.Offset(, 1)


rngNewCol.Value = "Employee Classifications"
With rngNewCol.Offset(1).Resize(lRow)
    .NumberFormat = "General"   'Set column to General format
    .Formula = "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your issue is with a changing source rather than with the if statement. If the source is changeable, I would suggest a dynamic solution, though it will certainly need a regular update/revision. Anyhow, as a 1st step, I would find the fixed points, like "Employee SGrp" string in the 1st row.

```
Dim rFnd As Range
Dim iEmpCol as Long   ' column number where the employees are
rFnd = Range(1:1).Find(What:="Employee SGrp")
If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
     iEmpCol = rFnd.Column
     ....
```

As we know the column where the data is, you can generate formulas this way:

```
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iTargetCol As Long

Cells(iRow, iTargetCol).Formulalocal = "=if(" & Cells(iRow, iEmpCol).Address & "=""Marketing"",1,2)"
```

All you need to do is to glue the strings and .Address references. Note the double quote inside the string.